# Can't open LibreOffice Draw

Tags: libreoffice

On trying to open LibreOffice Draw from Applications, a window appears: "LibreOffice 7.3 - Due to an error, LibreOffice crashed.... The following files will be recovered." The list of files is blank. Then on pressing OK the message is "LibreOffice will attempt to recover...." with a list containing only Untitled 1. I do Discard and Yes and it goes back to the LibreOffice window without having opened Draw.

I've tried uninstalling & reinstalling Draw from the software centre and from a terminal. There is no problem with other LibreOffice modules. Using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: is that also the case if you press `Super` type in `Draw` and select it from there?  The reason there is no file to recover is that you didn't save one in the first place. Do you have an old .odg file you can try opening?

Answer (score 2):

Neil: do you have Impress installed?
It might be a different issue, but I couldn't start Draw until I installed also Impress:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-impress
```

Apparently Draw and Impress can't be installed separately, see also:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/2017412

Comment: I had the exact same problem as the question author, even the same version of Ubuntu, and this solved it for me! I had installed libreoffice-draw from command line, but not libreoffice-impress

Answer (score 1):

Maybe move your old (and perhaps corrupt) LibreOffice config out of the way?

```
mv ~/.config/libreoffice ~/.config/old_libreoffice
```

Comment: I just encountered this same bug. Other Libreoffice apps work fine, it's just Draw. Moved the .config/libreoffice dir out of the way, same result. Runnig 'lodraw --safe-mode': same thing. No error message for me, though; the window appears for a couple of seconds and then it closes. This in 22.04 with Wayland